# Scrollify.js navigation issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-scrollify

Am using `scrollify.js` for page scroll. And i have my custom navigation bar which used to scroll by using offsetTop.

```
$(".fixed-nav a").click(function(evn) {
    evn.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

My page has scrollfying section as well as normal sections too. That is I have 6 sections, first three of them are scrollfy section and remaining three are normal sections.

Everything working fine. But issue is when I click on 6th **(that is non-scrollify section)** section from 1st section, it landed on 3rd **(that is last scrollify section)** section, instead of landing on 6th section.

Here is [fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/rajsnd08/eve8sd3g/1/) for reference. Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not able to find any solution or suggestion. So I wrote my own definition to resolve my issue. This helped me.

When I click a navigation which doesn't have scrollify effect, then I used `$.scrollify.instantMove()` to move to last scrollify section, then use normal `scrollTop` jquery to navigate to desire section.

```
$(".fixed-nav a").click(function(evn) {
    evn.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).hasClass('no-scroll') && (!$(this).closest('li').siblings('.active').find('a').hasClass('no-scroll'))) {
      $.scrollify.instantMove('#3');
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
      }, 500);
    } else {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
      }, 500);
    }
  });
});
```

Find this [fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/rajsnd08/eve8sd3g/15/) for reference.